# jQuery avoid rebinding as elements are added to a page

Tags: jquery, function, events, initialization, bind

I've got a big complicated method bound to all inputs on a page. Sometimes, however, inputs are dynamically added to the page and therefore arn't bound to the same method. I thought that I could be clever by binding the event to a variable, and updating the variable with the additional inputs as they're added to the page... but no.

I.e.

```
inputs.click(function(){ // stuff });

// add inputs to page

inputs = $('input');
```

Is there a sneakier way to do this? OBV I can throw the whole shebang `($('input').click()...)` in a function and reinitliaze that way... but surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind events to elements that are already on the page so use `on()` and bind to the closest ancestor of the dynamic inputs that is already present on the page, such as the form itself:

```
$('form').on('change', 'input', function() {
    // do something
});
```

The first string is a white-space separated list of events on which to react, the second is a jQuery selector to identify the targets of the events (if not the `form` itself).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jQuery.com/on).